# How to know which arguments are passed as parameters in anonymous functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am completely new to Javascript and I'm wondering how the anonymous functions know which arguments are being passed as parameters. Let me explain my doubt with the help of code:

```
camelize = function camelize(str) {
      return str.replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(match, chr)
       {
            return chr.toUpperCase();
        });
    }

console.log(camelize("JavaScript Exercises"));
console.log(camelize("JavaScript exercises"));
console.log(camelize("JavaScriptExercises"));
```

This code is supposed to return a camelcase version of the input string. I understand that the regex finds non-word characters globally. But how does the function inside know what are "match" and "chr"?

Comment: Do you realise that you are passing a _function_ into `replace`, and that `match` and `chr` are the function's parameters? If you understand that much, you should not be surprised that "`match` and `chr` have not been defined before", because they are function parameters.

Comment: the function definition is already defined inside the str.replace method, you are just plugging in an anonymous function in this case, but it would have to match the function definition in order to work. you couldn't for example, do str.replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(an_extra_argument, match, chr) {

}), as the anonymous function doesn't fit the expected definition

Comment: See also the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function accepts a function as its second parameter which it then calls, passing the results of the regex as the parameters of your function.

Here's an example of how one could implement a similar pattern

```js
function foo(str, func) {
  for(let i in str) { //for every character
      func(i, str[i]); // call func with the index and character
  } 
}


foo("hello world", function(index, char) {
console.log(index, char);
});
```